# Place a large block of code outside of 'if' statement within a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

```
$('#dgInput').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // here is a huge code block
}
```

To improve readability I need to place the code outside of `if` statement.

I tried -  `$('#dgInput').on('keypress', function(e.keyCode = 13) {` - doesn't work

Also - `if (e.keyCode == 13) {continue;}` - doesn't work.

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you provide more info?

Comment: If you want to improve readability you can divide your code into sections or just make sure your indenting is up to standard ?

Comment: what is the function? Is it re-usable (can just create a function, and call it inside the e.keyCode conditional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor the existing code block into a function:

```
function doStuff(param1, param2){
  // Work with the paramters here
  // Do some other things
  // May be, return a value
}
```

The `doStuff` function can be called from the original code:

```
$('#dgInput').on('keypress', function(e) {
                                 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                      // Do some initial work here
                                      let result = doStuff(param1, param2);
                                      // May be, do something with the result here
                                 }
}
```

In case the `doStuff` function is really large, it can be further refactored as multiple manageable functions - `doStuff` calls `doThis`, etc. In, general a function with 5 to 10 lines of code, preferably with related functionality (e.g., a calculate tax function accepts some parameters like amount, rate, discount and then returns the tax value), makes it readable and hence maintainable.

There is quite a bit of information related to code refactoring out there. It applies to all languages, generally. Little bit of research on the net can also help with ideas you may find useful.

EDIT:

Note that there is no rule that there should be one function (like, doStuff) within the `if` block. One can call multiple functions, like this within the block (and sometimes these functions can be reusable).

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // Do some initial work here
    let result = doStuff(param1, param2);
    doStuff2(result);
    doStuff3();
    // Do something with the result here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a function and use it inside.

```
function doSomeMagic(){
  // Do some magic here
}


$('#dgInput').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // here is a huge code block
    doSomeMagic();
  }
}
```

OR

```
function handleOnEnterPress(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   // here is a huge code block
 }
}


$('#dgInput').on('keypress', function(e) {
  handleOnEnterPress(e);
}
```

Comment: creating a new function to improve readability - let's say - an edge solution

Comment: Yes if you want more readibity ==>> name function like `onEnterPress` and pass `e` as parms and  do `e.keyCode == 13` check in function itself

Answer (score 4):

If you want to exit a function, use `return`, not `continue`.

```
if (e.keyCode != 13) {
    return;
}
// Large block of code now goes here
```

If you want to just move a large block of code (i.e. if you want to do stuff after the `if` condition) then put it in a function, and call that function from within your condition.

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    do_the_thing(e);
}
// Do more things
```